# Wedge buffering in qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I having difficulty with the wedge buffering tool in qgis ([Wedge Buffer Tool](https://github.com/Septima/qgis-wedgebuffer)). I applied the tool to a point shapefile (with about 15 points) that I created in arcgis pro.

Problem #1 is that the wedge buffers are all on top of each other - the vertices are based on only one point, whereas I assumed they would be based on each of the 15 points.

Problem #2 is that they are not mapped in the correct location. The original 15 points are located in Massachusetts and the wedge buffers are located in the midwest. They seem to be in the same projection, but I am very inexperienced in qgis. I use arcmap everyday, but decided to try qgis for the wedge buffering (which doesn't seem to be an option in arcgis unfortunately).

I can provide shapefiles if helpful.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the attribute table for at least some of your points, and tell us what you used in the wedge buffer dialog? What's the coordinate system of your point shapefile?

Comment: I would guess that your buffer lengths are in degrees (and a lot of them too), so each one looks like it's centred in the same place.

Comment: Buffer lengths do have to be in the same units as your data, so if your data is lat-long then a wedge of size 100 is 100 degrees, or most of the planet, and so when you can see the wedges all your points in Mass. will appear coincident.